# Help with asp.net mvc EditorFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, templates, editortemplates, mvc-editor-templates

I have a Project model and a Task model.

say in my controller I have

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
   Project p = new Project();
   Task t1=new Task();
   Task t2=new Task();
   Task t3=new Task();
   p.tasks.Add(t1);
   p.tasks.Add(t2);
   p.tasks.Add(t3);
}
```

and in my strongly typed View for Project I have

```
Html.EditorForModel()
```

How can I make this show the fields for the Project and also for each task?

please help!

-------Added for clarification

```
public ActionResult Create(Guid LicenseId)
        {
            License license;
            if (!User.IsInRole("admin"))
                license = _service.GetContributor(User.Identity.Name).Licenses.Single(l => l.Id == LicenseId);
            else
                license = _service.GetLicenseById(LicenseId);
            if (license == null)
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            IncomeDeclaration i = new IncomeDeclaration();
            foreach(var ecoActLicense in license.EconomicActivitiyLicenses)
            {
                EconomicActivityIncomeDeclaration ecoActIncDec = new EconomicActivityIncomeDeclaration();
                ecoActIncDec.ActivityTax = 20;
                ecoActIncDec.EconomicActivityId = ecoActLicense.EconomicActivityId;
                i.EconomicActivityIncomeDeclarations.Add(ecoActIncDec);
            }
            return View(i);
        }
```

This code is where I first relate the EconomicActivityIncomeDeclarations to the IncomeDeclaration.

and in the View, which is strongly typed for IncomeDeclaration I simply have

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>IncomeDeclaration</legend>

        @Html.EditorForModel()
        @Html.EditorFor(m =>m.EconomicActivityIncomeDeclarations)
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view should be strongly typed to the Project as the model, and if it is it should mostly just work automatically.

The public properties on Project (if it's the specified model for a strongly typed view), will be discovered and presented with Labels and textboxes for editing.

If you want to show the editor for a property that is a collection you could do something like:

```
Html.EditorForModel(model => model.tasks)
```

If necessary you can add an EditorTemplate for your collection item: `Views-->Shared-->EditorTemplates-->Task.cshtml`.

Comment: its showing me the fields for the Project but its not showing the fields for each Task!

Comment: Ah, so the collection of tasks needs to be specified... give me a couple minutes..

Comment: So I dont have to do any kind of foreach?

Comment: No, the EditorForModel should just figure it out... I have done it with a custom view for the items in the collection, but I don't think the custom view is needed, and I didn't have to enumerate the collection.

Comment: weird.. I cant get it to work... after adding the editor for the collection its just displaying some GUID instead of showing me textboxes... I had to use EditorFor instead of EditorForModel btw

Comment: Can you show the code for `Project` ?  Also are you using MVC 3?

Comment: .. its not actually Project model.. I just wanted to present this question as simply as possible... yes, it is mvc3. I used POCO templates to create the classes Im using.... my class is actually IncomeDeclaration which can have many EconomicActivityIncomeDeclarations.... but dont mind that.. wwhat should I look for in the IncomeDeclaration class?

Comment: Does IncomeDeclaration actually have an enumerable public property of EconomicActivityIncomeDeclarations?  Or is the relationship implicit in an id (which would explain the GUID).  Also does the EconomicActivityIncomeDeclarations class have public properties?

Comment: IncomeDeclaration has  a public virtual ICollection<EconomicActivityIncomeDeclaration> EconomicActivityIncomeDeclarations property... and EconomicActivityIncomeDeclaration has many public properties

Comment: It's possible that you have to have an EditorTemplate for EconomicActivityIncomeDeclarations... I'll update the answer.

Comment: I have added some code to the question... also, I am sure that the foreach is iterating at least once (for the case Im trying out) so it should display at least once the fields for a EconomicActivityIncomeDeclaration

Comment: I would use EditorForModel on the collection rather than EditorFor

Comment: The thing is EditorForModel doesnt take a lambda expression

Comment: You're right; I just went back to my code and re-read it... sorry! EditorFor with an EditorTemplate should work.

Comment: I have both, but I think it will work with just EconomicActivityIncomeDeclaration.

Comment: Ok, Im marking you as answer. thanks for all the help!... I guess Ill google how to create your own EditorTemplate... Thanks again

Comment: Could my problem have something to do with http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-4-custom-object-templates.html "Shallow Dive vs. Deep Dive"?...

Comment: It's possible... I haven't experimented with the Shallow vs. Deep dive things Brad talks about.